# How to open pdf file from SD card in webview in android

Tags: android, pdf

How to open Sd card pdf file in Webview without using Intent in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You cant open pdf directly in android web browser.

> Use Google Docs in a WebView Like this : [Read pdf file from sd-card with the help of webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434487/open-pdf-in-a-webview)

Comment: Tnx for quick response, I want to open pdf file from Sd card in Webview not from URL.

Answer (score 0):

> How to open Sd card pdf file in Webview without using Intent in Android?

Generally, you can't. `WebView` does not have any native ability to display PDF files. You are welcome to attempt to get `PDF.js` to work, as is discussed in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757425/mozilla-pdf-js-webview-ask-for-internet).

Comment: yeah just use pdfjs it's nice!