# Open file such as doc,xls,pdf from sdcard to webview in android

Tags: android

Is there any way to load and open files such as doc,docx,xls,pdf,etc. from sdcard to webview?

Comment: not possible for pdf file, but here there is one solution written by Commonsware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712140/how-to-open-pdf-file-from-sd-card-in-webview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

WebView can not open these files. You need to open them in a corresponding app like Microsoft Word, Excel, ... and Google PDF Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not open files in webview directly from sdcard, but alternet solution is you can upload them in google drive first and can open it in webview. like below.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: thanks mehul....it is also showing "no preview available" and i am also looking for other types file such as doc, xls, etc.

Comment: it will work for all type of files supported by google drive.

Comment: it should...but it is showing no preview available.

Comment: try to open this url : http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: yes Mehul..that url is working fine But, I am trying to load pdf file from sdcard..that is why i am not able to open.